# Typescript: how to pass variable with complex type to a function without redefining type

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I am kind of new to typescript and I had this a few times now. I use for example prisma (or anything) to get a value which's type is monstrously complex (as in long).

It has many attributes and those are perfectly fine. As soon as I want to define a function to handle this value, I lose all the type information since I'd have to redefine this complex type in the parameter.

Example:

```
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
        select:{
            projects: {
                select: {
                    name: true,
                    slug: true,
                    _count:{
                        select: {
                            subscribers: true,
                            mediaIds: true
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            id: true,
            email: true,
            firstName: true,
            lastName: true,
            createdAt: true,
            _count:{
                select:{
                    mediaIds: true,
                    projects: true
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

And now I want to define a function to for example handle one single of those subscribers:

```
users.forEach(user=>{
  // here I have perfect typing for the user object
  handleUser(user)
});
function handleUser(user: <what to put here?>){
  // here I'd have to retype / redefine the monstreously long (but helpful) dynamic type that prisma creates for my query
}
```

I am confused what the common approach is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `users` array is avaiable in the scope of the function, you could use the `typeof` operator.

```
function handleUser(user: typeof users[number]){
  
}
```

You can index the `typeof users` with `number` to get the type of an array element inside `users`.

Comment: that's already better than what I have. It still feels a little hacky but this works at least :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class that define the `User` model. You define the model one time in the orm file and then you can use the `User` type to type your parameters. Typescript cannot know that the param user is an user so you have to type it

```js
function handleUser(user: User){
  // handle the user
}
```

Comment: I'd like to do that but since I included data from a relation (similar to a join in sql or lookup in mongodb) it means this is no ordinary User model but a very special one (hence the typing is not just User but a very long one that includes user)

Answer (score 0):

To define a large type in TypeScript, use `interface` for objects, or `type` for tiny details.

Example:

```js
interface HumanType {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const human: HumanType = { name: "Thomas", age: 34588 }
```

In this example, if you have a class that defines a Human, use it as a type.

Comment: I included data from a relation (similar to a join in sql or lookup in mongodb) which means this is no ordinary User / HumanType model but a very special one (hence the typing is not just User but a very long one that includes User)